# Why does the browser jumps to ID when changing hash?

Tags: javascript, anchor, hashtag

Assume I have following markup:

```
<div id ="About" style="height: 2000px">
    About
</div>
<div id="Work" style="height: 2000px">
    Work
</div>
```

When I run `location.hash = 'Work';` the browser jumps right to the position of the "Work" element. I was expecting that behaviour with an anchor tag with a name attribute. But in our case it is a `div` container with an ID. I tested this in IE8/9 and Chrome.

**Why does the browser jumps to the `div` container when changing the hash?**

For your convenience I openend a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Rbt/).

Comment: Another name of `hash` is `fragment`. Its usually used to show a site fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature. It is designed so and you can read about it in [rfc2854](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2854.txt). Let me quote it for you:

> Fragment Identifiers
>
> The URI specification [URI] notes that the semantics of a fragment 
>   identifier (part of a URI after a "#") is a property of the data
>   resulting from a retrieval action, and that the format and
>   interpretation of fragment identifiers is dependent on the media type 
>   of the retrieval result.
>
> For documents labeled as text/html, the fragment identifier
>   designates the correspondingly named element; any element may be
>   named with the "id" attribute, and A, APPLET, FRAME, IFRAME, IMG and
>   MAP elements may be named with a "name" attribute.  This is described 
>   in detail in [HTML40] section 12.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just anchors with name attributes, anything with an ID can be jumped to using location.hash or just #Work in the url.

For example, clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192871/why-does-the-browser-jumps-to-id-when-changing-hash/13192907#show-editor-button) will take you to the id `#show-editor-button` in this page

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that kind of behaviour?

Comment: Something like `$(".prevent").click(function(e) {   e.preventDefault();
});` would work, if the divs all had a class of prevent.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just do onclick="return false"

Comment: Well, I do want to have JS running, when clicking a button, but I do not want to jump to the corresponding element on the page.

Comment: @Amberlamps You can still use preventDefault then, it is not a jquery function, it is a w3c specification, see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation

Comment: or maybe consider changing your id's ;) it would be easy and straight forward way.

Comment: @yakxxx: This is actually what I did :)